# match exact string in a sentence

Tags: javascript

How to exactly match a given string in a sentence.

For example if the sentence is 
var sentence = "A Google wave is basically a document which captures a communication"

and the given string is 
var inputString= "Google Wave". I need to check the exact presence of Google Wave in the above sentence & return true or false.

I tried

```
if(sentence.match(inputString)==null){
            alert("No such word combination found.");
        return false;
        }
```

This works even if someone enters "Google W". I need a way to find the exact match. Please help

Comment: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: indexOf will return a substring as well which is not what he is asking.  See my answer below for a potential solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP wants to return false when do search with `Google W`.

I think you should use word boundary for regular expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Sample:

```
inputString = "\\b" + inputString.replace(" ", "\\b \\b") + "\\b";
if(sentence.toLowerCase().match(inputString.toLowerCase())==null){
    alert("No such word combination found.");
}
```

Comment: @dazzle This is a good question that I might need the answer some day as well. Please mark as answered if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Using javascript's [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
var str = "A Google wave is basically a document which captures a communication";
if (str.indexOf("Google Wave") !== -1){
  // found it
}
```

For your case-insensitive comparison, and to make it easier:

```
// makes any string have the function ".contains([search term[, make it insensitive]])"
// usage:
//   var str = "Hello, world!";
//   str.contains("hello") // false, it's case sensitive
//   str.contains("hello",true) // true, the "True" parameter makes it ignore case
String.prototype.contains = function(needle, insensitive){
  insensitive = insensitive || false;
  return (!insensitive ?
    this.indexOf(needle) !== -1 :
    this.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );
}
```

*Oop, wrong doc reference. Was referencing array.indexOf*

Comment: @Michael Jasper: The OP is asking for 'exact presence', so in his example I guess he expects `false`.

Comment: @MichaelJasper: How's that? ;-) (Though @pimvdb is correct, OP wanted "Google Wave" exactly)

Comment: What if the sentence is `"Two Google WAVES is basically a document which captures a communication"` I believe your function would return true, event though `"Google Wave".toLowerCase() !== "Google Waves".toLowerCase()`

Comment: @seebiscuit see previous comments about exact match.

Answer (score 0):

ContainsExactString2 was just me going more in-depth than necessary, '===' should work just fine

```
<input id="execute" type="button" value="Execute" />

// Contains Exact String

$(function() {
    var s = "HeyBro how are you doing today";
    var a = "Hey";
    var b = "HeyBro";
    $('#execute').bind('click', function(undefined) {
        ContainsExactString(s, a);
        ContainsExactString(s, b);
    });
});

function ContainsExactString2(sentence, compare) {
    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        var word = words[i];
        var pos = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < word.length; ++j) {
            if (word[j] !== compare[pos]) {
                console.log("breaking");
                break;
            }
            if ((j + 1) >= word.length) {
                alert("Word was found!!!");
                return;
            }++pos;
        }
    }
    alert("Word was not found");
}

function ContainsExactString(sentence, compare) {
    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        if(words[i] === compare) {
            alert("found " + compare);
            break;
        }
    }
    alert("Could not find the word");
    break;
}
```

Comment: I didnt fully test this, i was just trying it for fun, but this was sort of how i got it to work